# Wordpress ACF Repeater Layout

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In Wordpress I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to make a repeater.

I would like the repeater in the admin to stack 3 across to optimize the space better, but adding a width to the 'Wrapper Attributes' only serves to make it smaller but still puts the next one below (seems pointless?).

Instead I thought I could set the layout to Block and use my admin.css to put them side by side, however the repeater is always wrapped in a table regardless of what the layout is set to. So for the time being I have added css to make the table rows inline-blocks.

Is there a way to do this from within the ACF settings?

Comment: No, but it would be nice if there was.